# Merging Subswaths with ERDAS Imagine

Tags: erdas-imagine

Does anyone have experience with merging subswaths of a SLC Sentinel 1 image in ERDAS Imagine? I cannot find the right function for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's important to ask the Question you want answered. In this case you've asked if anyone has experience with the software, which can only be answered "Yes," without any benefit to your real need. Please [Edit] the Question to state what you have tried, and what problem you have encountered, and ask an answerable question in the context of that attempt.